# SpreadsheetNotFound: How to authorize a gspread email account

Tags: python, gspread

I have the following code:

```
import gspread as gs
import gspread_dataframe as gd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

path_cred = '0_Credentials/dashboard-7ebfec2b3590.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path_cred, scope)

file = gs.authorize(credentials)

ws = file.open("output_forecast").worksheet("summary")
```

When that last line runs, it gives me this error:

```
SpreadsheetNotFound
```

I followed the instructions online + stack overflow responses which said to share the spreadsheet with the client email (from the json credentials ending in "iam.gserviceaccount.com"). I did this, but I am still encountering the error.

Comment: Any luck trying to open the spreadsheet by key? 


ex. `gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')` where the big base64 string is part of the url of your spreadsheet.

Comment: That works - thank you!!